# ElasticSearch boost not working in match_phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running ElasticSearch 1.5.2 and trying to boost a filter within a ES query as below:

```
{
    "match_phrase": {
        "business_names_wpm": {
            "query": "phrase",
            "boost": 10
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be making any difference, there was an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13129) raised that `boost` was being ignored in `match_phrase_prefix`, I am not sure if it's irrelevant to `match_phrase`.

Comment: I just tried this on my machine with ES versions 2.3.1 and 5.2.1. Works on the newer one, but does not affect scores on 2.3.1. I'm not sure if it's the same bug, but it seems fixed in later ES versions.

Comment: Thank you for trying it out on newer version.